# sp_executesql & missing parameter error

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have this SQL statement

```
exec sp_executesql N'test', N'@name varchar(10)', @name=N'john'
```

which is giving an error in SQL Server 2012:

> Procedure or function 'test' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied.

The procedure definition is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    @name varchar(10) 
AS
BEGIN
    select @name
END
```

The SQL is generated from C# using `BeginExecuteReader` command on the `SqlCommand` object and the parameter was added to the parameters collection using:

```
new SqlParameter("@" + parametername, sqldbType, size)
```

and then setting the value.

What is causing the error?

Because the SQL is not generated by hand, I am looking for an answer which makes `SqlCommand` generate a working SQL or modify the stored procedure to make it work with the generated SQL from .NET. As a test, I added a default value for the name parameter and the error went away but the value of name is not there. There's a disconnect somewhere.

Comment: the definition of stored procedure and the statement you are having problem with, what is their relation? how you are using `sp_executesql` inside your stored procedure?

Comment: @M.Ali I don't understand your question. sp_executesql is not used inside the sp. sp_executesql executes the sp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this syntax:

```
exec sp_executesql N'exec dbo.test @name',N'@name varchar(10)',@name=N'john'
```

Comment: There are 3 exec/sp_execute calls here. Does it really have to be so many just to invoke a procedure?

Comment: @usr It's a single call and I don't control it. ADO.NET creates it.

Comment: @Abdu maybe you need to set CommandType to StoredProcedure? If ADO.NET always generated code like this it would be quite a useless framework.

Comment: @usr You're right! I forgot to set the command type and so ado.net treated it as a dynamic sql statement which I incorrectly pieced  together. Now it works much better.